# Python-style dictionary in C++?

Tags: python, c++, arrays, list, dictionary

Beginner at C++ here. Was wondering if there is a function that is similar to dictionaries in Python. I am looking to create a list of keys with their assigned values which can be easily referenced by a numerated pointer like this: myDict['insert position of key']. Oh and the data inserted will be strings. Thanks in advance.

I want to make a dictionary of names as keys with the number of coins (spoof) they have in their hands. This will all be entered with cin.

Comment: *"Oh and the data inserted will be strings."* doesn't mesh with *" dictionary of names as keys with the number of coins"*: is the mapped-to data `string`s or numbers?

Answer (score 3):

`std::map` and `std::unordered_map` will behave very similar in a lot of cases. However, they are different data structures, `std::map` is implemented using a tree, and `std::unordered_map` uses a hash table. Since python `dict` is implemented as a hash table, `std::unordered_map` is more similar; it has the same asymptotic properties.

Very basic example of using `std::unordered_map`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

int main()
{
  // declare and initialize the "dictionary"
  std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> my_dict = {{"cat", "dog"}, {"apple", "book"}};

  // insert values
  my_dict.insert(std::make_pair("horse", "tree"));
  my_dict["pig"] = "sky";

  for (auto it=my_dict.begin(); it != my_dict.end(); it++)
  {
    std::cout << "key : " << it->first << " value " << it->second << std::endl;
  }

  // .count() to check if elements exists in unordered_map
  std::cout << my_dict.count("cat") << std::endl;
  std::cout << my_dict.count("wolf") << std::endl;

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This would typically be something like

```
std::map<std::string, std::string>
```

or

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string>
```

But be sure to study the interface carefully. For example, element access and checking whether a key exists may not have the syntax that you expect, and seemingly familiar syntax may do something unexpected.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have tried this but with the knowledge I currently have, it is hard for me to reference the key without typing out the whole string specifically.

Comment: @Jonathan358: bit hard to know what you mean by that, but say you have a `std::string` that you've read in, you can create a reference to an element in the map (which using the following code will be inserted with value 0 if not already there) `std::map<std::string, int> my_map; while (getline(std::cin, my_string) { int& number_of_coins = my_map[my_string]; number_of_coins += 3; }`.  As Kerrek says, study the interface ([here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map)).

Comment: `std::unordered_map` is more similar to python `dict` than `std::map`, since `std::unordered_map` and `dict` are hash tables, while `std::map` as a tree.